# Wxpython: Изменение свойств окна в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: python, wxpython

В классе есть переменная-флаг `isChanged`, которая принимает значения `True`/`False`. Данная переменная меняет свое состояние на `истину` когда были внесены какие-то изменения в проект, и на `ложь`, когда проект был сохранен. Можно ли как-то отследить момент изменения значения этой переменной, чтобы в зависимости от ее значения делать кнопки (например, сохранить) активными или нет. Может можно как-то сгенерировать событие?

Comment: Добавьте код с этой переменной. Мб это простой `Bool`, а мб это setter/getter описанный через `@property` :)

Comment: @gil9red простой bool. Например при добавлении элемента на схемы isChanged=True, если мы сохраняем проект isChanged=False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно обернуть свойство в `getter`/`setter` методы и в них выполнять какие-то дополнительные действия пример:

```
# Класс с обычным свойством
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_changed = False


# Класс с свойством с использованием getter/setter методов
class Foo2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__is_changed = False

    def set_is_changed(self, value):
        print('set is_changed. new value: {}, old: {}'.format(value, self.__is_changed))

        self.__is_changed = value

    def get_is_changed(self):
        return self.__is_changed

    is_changed = property(get_is_changed, set_is_changed)


f1 = Foo()
f1.is_changed = True

f2 = Foo2()
f2.is_changed = True
f2.is_changed = False
```

Консоль:

```
set is_changed. new value: True, old: False
set is_changed. new value: False, old: True
```