# Как сделать неизменяемую переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные, типы-данных

У меня есть переменная. В ходе программы она меняться не должна. Хочу сделать нечто вроде константы, которую ни намеренно, ни случайно изменить будет нельзя. (хотелось бы также, чтобы от этого она меньше занимала места). Для списков есть кортежи (неизменяемые списки), а вот для переменных что можно использовать?
Можно ли сделать неизменяемый словарь?

Comment: _В ходе программы она меняться не должна_ - ну так не меняйте ее в своей программе.

Comment: Переменную можно сделать такой только если она будет в объекте/классе. Просто так нельзя запретить ей присваивать значения. Добавьте пример вашего кода, который показывает когда не нужно менять значение

Comment: @gil9red Пример кода тут не уместен. Я ввел переменные-параметры, чтобы если вдруг надо будет их изменить, не лазить по всех программе и не  менять эти параметры, а просто поменять их вначале кода.  Но так как их будет много, хотелось бы уменьшить в размере и сделать неизменяемыми.

Comment: Это вы думаете что неуместен, то, что вы сказали это интересная инфа. Получается, вам нужно константы, которые нужно объявить в одном месте и не позволить их менять?

Comment: @gil9red Да, но я не нашел такого в интернете

Comment: в питоне нет констант самих по себе, разве что указание что переменные в верхнем регистре ими типо считаются, но никто не помешает их менять, но IDE по идеи могут "ругаться" на такие вещи

Comment: Кроме вас никто не изменит значение переменных в коде, поэтому **достаточно придерживаться правил их именования**, чтобы избежать коллизий. Подход с `read-only` аттрибутами класса имеет смысл только если вы создаете библиотеку или `api`, которыми будут пользоваться другие разработчики.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно сделать через [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Const(NamedTuple):
    VALUE_1 = "ABC"
    VALUE_2 = 1000

CONST = Const()


print(CONST.VALUE_1)  # ABC
print(CONST.VALUE_2)  # 1000
print()

CONST.VALUE_1 = 100  # AttributeError: 'Const' object attribute 'VALUE_1' is read-only
print(CONST.VALUE_1)
```

---

Тоже самое, но вручную:

```
class Const:
    VALUE_1 = property(fget=lambda self: "ABC")
    VALUE_2 = property(fget=lambda self: 1000)

CONST = Const()


print(CONST.VALUE_1)  # ABC
print(CONST.VALUE_2)  # 1000
print()

CONST.VALUE_1 = 100  # AttributeError: can't set attribute
print(CONST.VALUE_1)
```

Comment: интересное решение!  я раньше такого не встречал...

Comment: это по сути то же самое чего хочет избежать автор, только вид сбоку, поскольку в CONST все равно можно записать всё что угодно.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы хотите, чтобы в переменную не могли записать значения, то можно, например, сделать её закрытым членом класса, а в открытых методах реализовать доступ к этой переменной.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.__bar = bar

    def get(self):
        return self.__bar


biz = Foo(42)
>>> biz.get()
42
>>> biz.__bar
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__bar'
```

Также думаю стоит сказать немного про типы данных в Python. В Python все типы данных делятся на изменяемые (mutable) и неизменяемые (unmutable). К изменяемым относятся:

- списки (list)
- множества (set)
- словари (dict)

К неизменяемым:

- числа (int, float, double)
- строки (str)
- кортежи (tuple)

Рассмотрим случай с неизменяемыми типами. Когда Вы инициализируете переменную, например

```
a = 42
```

то в памяти создаётся объект, содержащий данное значение и ссылка на объект присваивается переменной a. Адрес объекта можно узнать с помощью функции id

```
>>> id(a)
1848305056
```

Если теперь мы изменим значение переменной

```
a = a + 1
```

то, она будет хранить ссылку на другой объект в области памяти:

```
>>> id(a)
1848305072
```

Но если мы попробуем проделать такие же операции с каким-либо изменяемым типом, например, списком, то увидим, что переменная продолжает хранить ссылку на тот же объект:

```
>>> spam = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(spam)
48769064
>>> spam.append(4)
>>> id(spam)
48769064
```

Comment: Пример с `__bar` не самый удачный, попробуйте обернуть переменную в `property`, посмотрите пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847770/201445

Comment: biz = Foo(42)

print(biz.get())

biz._Foo__bar = 7

print(biz.get())

Comment: ее так можно поменять